# Passing byte[] as a parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following code where I try to pass a byte array as a parameter to a stored procedure.

```
DbCommand ac = new DbCommand(connIn);
ac.ParamAdd("p_id", jobId);
byte[] zippedAuditLog = ZipFile(auditLog);
ac.ParamAdd("p_audit_log", zippedAuditLog);
ac.ParamAdd("p_mod_user", userId);

ac.ExecuteStoredProc("pkg.audit_log_update");
```

If I debug the C# code the `zippedAuditLog` byte array is populated correctly, however on save to the database the value is being set to `0x1F` which is just a blank space.

The database procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE job_pkg.audit_log_update
    @p_id        INT,       
    @p_audit_log VARBINARY(MAX),
    @p_mod_user  VARCHAR(60),
    @p_status    VARCHAR(60) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_job
    SET zipped_audit_log = @p_audit_log
    WHERE id = @p_id
END
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The ParamAdd code is shown below:

```
    public SqlParameter ParamAdd(string name, object val) {
        if (val == null)
            return command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
        else
            return command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, val);
    }
```

Comment: `ParamAdd` is clearly a custom function: what is its implementation?

Comment: Indeed, how does that function determine the type of the parameter?

Comment: The code for `ParamAdd` is prone to issues, [please fix that](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).